# How to create connection in new server registration wizard for reporting service on ssms?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

[image]I have been trying to register new server(reporting server) on sql managment studio but i am getting error on that.Please help me how to do that .I want to deply ssrs reports using that.I am using windows authentication but test connection is failing.Which connection i have to use on this.

Comment: post error screenshot for better clearance.

Comment: You cannot deploy SSRS reports using SSMS, you do that via Visual Studio, or BIDS. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159270.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396